# QAbstractListModel: update role names

Tags: c++, qt, model-view-controller, qml, qabstractitemmodel

I'm trying to create a List model based on an asynchronous database api. Here is a qml example of how I want to be able to use it:

```
ListView {
    id: view;

    anchors.fill: parent;

    model: DatabaseModel {
        id: dmodel

        query: "SELECT id FROM test"
        database: "toto.sqlite"
    }

    delegate: Label {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;
        width: view.width / 2;
        height: 30;
        text: id;

        color: "teal";
    }
}
```

obviously at some point I'll need more than an id in my database and more than a Label to display this item.

To be able to use "id" in the definition of my Label I use role names like that :

```
QHash<int, QByteArray> DatabaseListModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> b = this->QAbstractItemModel::roleNames();

    if (m_query != "" && m_database) {
        QStringList l = m_database->currentRequestFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < l.count(); ++i) {
            b.insert(Qt::UserRole + i + 1, l.at(i).toLocal8Bit());
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

m_database being a database session to "toto.sqlite" in this case and m_query being "SELECT id FROM test".

The thing is that my database session is asynchronous and `m_database->currentRequestFields()` is not available immediately, However I receive a signal telling me when it is so I would like to update the roleNames list at this moment and not before.

Even if m_database will probably look like a blackbox, here is what I do to update the model:

```
void DatabaseListModel::updateModel()
{
    if (m_query != "" && m_database) {
        m_mutex.lock();
        beginResetModel();
        m_cache.clear();

        QObject::connect(m_database, &CollaoDatabase::databaseReady, this, [this] (CollaoDatabase* database) {
            database->setQueryStringi(m_query);
            database->executei(); //currentRequestFields() becomes available 
            database->fetchAlli();
            database->sendNotifierEventi(0); //when everything written before this line has been executed, ask the database to emit CollaoDatabase::notifierEventProcessed. It's not instant and might take a while depending on the query  
        });
        QObject::connect(m_database, &CollaoDatabase::resultReady, this, [this] (QVariantMap result) {
            if (m_cache.size() <= 0)
                m_cache.reserve(m_database->currentPendingFetches() + 1);
            m_cache.append(result.values());
        });

        QObject::connect(m_database, (void (CollaoDatabase::*)())&CollaoDatabase::notifierEventProcessed, this, [this](){
            endResetModel();
            //TODO: update roleNames here

            m_mutex.unlock();
            m_database = NULL; //as soon as stop() is called, we cannot assume the existance of this object anymore
            //it is therefore safer to make it null now
        });
        QObject::connect(m_database, SIGNAL(notifierEventProcessed()), m_database, SLOT(stop()));

        m_database->start();
    }
}
```

Comment: The rolenames should be updated before the endResetModel(). I'm not sure though that will work reliably, last time I debugged this, the QML views couldn't cope with changing role names, even if they only changed during a model reset.

Comment: Additionally I don't see a point in dynamically creating role names. How are you planning to update the QML delegate for changing role names? Couldn't you use "role001" to "role999" and put changing SQL column data into these fixed role names?

Comment: Actually role names are not "updating" their initialization is delayed but is done only once. I managed to make things kinda work by calling beginResetModel AFTER currentRequestFields() becomes available. As soon as I can remove the "kinda" of the previous sentence I'll post a working code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally got the behavior I wanted, which is being able to delay the first initialization of my itemModel's role names. The code is essentially the same with some reordering. Especially role names MUST be available BEFORE the call to beginResetModel. you can compare this snippet to the one in my question

```
void DatabaseListModel::updateModel()
{
    if (m_query != "" && m_database) {
        m_mutex.lock();

        QObject::connect(m_database, &CollaoDatabase::databaseReady, this, [this] (CollaoDatabase* database) {
            database->setQueryStringi(m_query);
            database->executei();
            database->sendNotifierEventi(1);
            database->fetchAlli();
            database->sendNotifierEventi(0);
        });
        QObject::connect(m_database, &CollaoDatabase::resultReady, this, [this] (QVariantMap result) {
            if (m_cache.size() <= 0) {
                m_fields = result.keys();
                beginResetModel();
                m_cache.reserve(m_database->currentPendingFetches() + 1);
                m_numRows = m_database->currentPendingFetches() + 1;
                emit numRowsChanged();
                m_progress = 0;
            }

            m_cache.append(result.values());
            ++m_progress;
            if (m_progress % (m_numRows / 100 + 1) == 0)
                emit progressChanged();
        });

        QObject::connect(m_database, (void (CollaoDatabase::*)(int))&CollaoDatabase::notifierEventProcessed, this, [this](int eventIndex){
            switch (eventIndex) {
            case 0: /*terminate*/
                emit progressChanged();
                endResetModel();
                m_mutex.unlock();
                m_database->stop();
                m_database = NULL; //as soon as stop() is called, we cannot assume the existance of this object anymore
                //it is therefore safer to make it null now
                break;

            case 1: /*now able to reset the model*/
                m_cache.clear();
                break;
            }
        });

        m_database->start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea that might fit your needs (guessing you want a nice api for users of this model and having SELECT queries only) is to structure your query the following way:

- String table
- String[] columns
- String selection
- String[] selectionArgs
- String groupBy
- String having
- String orderBy
- String limit

(Idea stolen from 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

So your simple example could look like

```
DatabaseModel {
    id: dmodel

    table: "test"
    colums: ["id"]
    database: "toto.sqlite"
}
```

That way you have the column names available early enough to use them for role namens.